# I have a problem to read processor id from txt file in fortran

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to create a Fortran code for defining processor id. I can write the processor id into a text file. The text file `pid2.txt` is created but I can not read it in Fortran. While I open the text file in `notepad` or `NotePad++` everything seems OK! In Fortran when I opening the text file it shows unknown parameter. Can any body help me with this problem?

The content of text file is

```
ProcessorId       
BFEBFBFF00010676
```

The sample code is as below:

```
program get_PID
implicit none
character(200) :: line
call system('wmic cpu get ProcessorId >pid2.txt ' )
open (1,file='pid2.txt')
read (1,*) line
read (1,*) line
CLOSE (1)   
end program
```

Do you have any advice?

Comment: Have you tried changing the IO-Unit? What version of Fortran and what compiler are you using? If you are using GCC you can call [GETPID](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GETPID.html) directly.

Comment: You are reading line twice, why? Otherwise please tell us the compiler and version of the compiler you are using, exactly how you compiled your program, and exactly what the error message is.

Comment: I'm using intel FORTRAN 2015 and compiling with visual studio 2013. the compiler dosent show error. I dont know how to change IO unit by this command "call system('wmic cpu get ProcessorId >pid2.txt ' )"

Comment: Please - it is spelt Fortran and has been officially for 3 decades. If there is no error why do you think this is wrong? I do not understand what you mean by "In Fortran when I opening the text file it shows unknown parameter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your case is the encoding of the ouput from `wmic`. Windows uses UTF-16 as default. Fortran cannot handle this encoding yet. Referring to the help of Intel Fortran, only UTF-8 is supported as described [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-open-encoding-specifier).

Therefore you have to change the encoding of the output to ANSI and/or your local codepage. This can be done by piping the result of `wmic` through the `more` command as described on SO superuser site under [combine-batch-wmic-ansi-unicode-output-formatting](https://superuser.com/a/812471/1038576).

Please change your system call as follows:

```
call system('wmic cpu get ProcessorId | more >pid2.txt ' )
```

You'll get the processor ID information in your code now, as expected.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi M Ch. Sound's good that this command solved your issue:). Could you mark this answer as the accepted one, please? Just press on the grey check mark on the left side of my post. Thanks.

Comment: It's Done Dear CKE